# Fluent NHibernate Disable Cache

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have problem with cache in Fluent NHibernate. I want to disable it for query by ID e.g.

```
session.Get<Person>(10);
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: It would be good if you could explain the issue you are having a little more.

Comment: You are maybe asking how to apply a wrong solution to your actual trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the first-level (session) cache?
You can refresh the state of an entity from the database by using Refresh, that is:

```
// Will get the state from the first-level cache if already present in the session:
var entity = Session.Get<EntityType>(entityId);

// Line below will update the entity with the current state from the database:
Session.Refresh(entity);
```

Comment: If the entity was not already in cache, this will cause two queries on database.

Comment: That's true. I believe that if the situation is like above (you don't have a reference to the entity you want to refresh) Session.Load could be used instead of Session.Get to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

If you already hold the entity, call directly `session.Refresh(person)` on it instead of getting it again.

You may also evict it with `session.Evict(person)`, causing it to no more be in the session, and no more tracked for changes either. Then discard it and eventually get it again later if you need.

Otherwise, this is unusual to consider it is a trouble getting it from the session cache. This is frequently a sign of bad session usage, such as using a same session across many user interactions (anti-pattern).

You can still do what [Fredy proposes](/a/44251961/1178314). Or call `session.Clear()` before getting for clearing the session cache (and losing all pending changes by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Person object that is mapped you could create a DTO for Person and do a QueryOver().

The PersonDTO object wont be cached in Nhibernates first-lvl-cache.